# How do I get an image to show on black only?

Tags: image, transparent

It's hard to go into details but there's not much to go about.

Let's say I wanted to make  this sponge show on black only. I know the sponge would have to become somewhat transparent (translucent)
[image: this sponge]

How would I make it only show on black? Like if it was on white it'd be transparent completely.

Comment: Hi txs, could you please specify what application/programming language you're using?

Comment: removed long title for image link, show image in question

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please show how the answer should look. Do you expect the yellow sponge to suddenly change colour? Or the white surround to become transparent so the surround adopts the colour of whatever you overaly it onto?